# certutil.exe is returning localized output

Tags: local, certutil

We have an PowerShell automation script that uses certutil.exe to list CA, issued certificates, etc... on a given Windows Server.

We wrapped some functions around a system Invoke of certutil.exe and we are grepping its output to look for some given patterns. However, in a French/German (and others for sure) installed Windows server, our script does not work at all, because certutil is returning localized outputs and it's impossible to predict that, and impossible to support all the languages of the world. Is there any way to force certutil.exe to print its output in English instead of the current machine language ?

I know that in Linux environment, we can do that:

```
LANG=en_EN.UTF-8 ls /tmp/toto
```

It will force ls to answer in English

Thanks for your help